# Paragraphs in android string resources not rendering in textview views

Tags: android, html, android-layout, paragraph

I tried to create a text with separate paragraphs in a string resource. The Android [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) states that `<p></p>` is supported, but it is ignored. I can insert a `\n`, but that doesnt insert any space between the paragraphs. I use `\n\n` as a work around, but 2 newlines simply wastes too much vertikal space.

Can I post-process the string in kotlin to fix that?

```
<string name="lorem_ipsum"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
<p>At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</p>
<p>Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p></string>
```

This is how it should look like:
[image: HTML rendering]

This is the result:
[image]

Comment: have you tried with HTML.fromHtml(); ?

Comment: Have you considered using a `WebView` instead of a `TextView`? Else the CSS support is rather limited. The HTML markup is not being ignored, but you cannot apply `p {}` CSS styles to it.